# Why does app crush with recharts components?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using recharts in my project (see example) and sometimes at all pages where I am using recahrts components I have got an error (see error), my app crush then I am reinstalling node modules and it's start work. I am using recharts@1.7.1 version. I don't understand why this error is appeared and how to resolve it. Will be grateful  for help.

```
  {dataWithoutNullValue.length > 0 && windowWidth &&
                        <PieChart width={windowWidth < 500 ? 300 : 500} height={windowWidth < 400 ? 350 : 400} >
                            <Pie
                                data={dataWithoutNullValue}
                                innerRadius={90}
                                outerRadius={125}
                                paddingAngle={5}
                                dataKey="value"
                                isAnimationActive={false}
                                label={windowWidth > 500 && renderCustomizedLabel}
                            >
                                {
                                    dataWithoutNullValue.map((entry, index) => <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />)
                                }
                            </Pie>
                            {windowWidth < 500 && <Legend dataKey="value" />}
                        </PieChart>}


Error

     ChartUtils.js:133 Uncaught TypeError: validateData.map is not a function
        at getDomainOfDataByKey (ChartUtils.js:133)
        at generateCategoricalChart.js:1019
        at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
        at CategoricalChartWrapper.getAxisMapByAxes (generateCategoricalChart.js:995)
        at CategoricalChartWrapper.getAxisMapByAxes (react-hot-loader.development.js:724)
        at CategoricalChartWrapper.getAxisMap (generateCategoricalChart.js:942)
        at CategoricalChartWrapper.getAxisMap (react-hot-loader.development.js:724)
        at generateCategoricalChart.js:1598
        at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
        at CategoricalChartWrapper.updateStateOfAxisMapsOffsetAndStackGroups (generateCategoricalChart.js:1596)
        at CategoricalChartWrapper.updateStateOfAxisMapsOffsetAndStackGroups (react-hot-loader.development.js:724)
        at new BarChart (generateCategoricalChart.js:830)
        at new BarChart (eval at ES6ProxyComponentFactory (react-hot-loader.development.js:337), <anonymous>:14:7)
        at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:12923)
        at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17060)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18538)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:189)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:238)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:291)
        at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23078)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22042)
        at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22018)
        at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21636)
        at react-dom.development.js:11148
        at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:659)
        at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11094)
        at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11143)
        at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11131)
        at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21079)
        at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:12693)
        at Connect.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:464)
        at Connect.onStateChange (connectAdvanced.js:205)
        at Connect.onStateChange (react-hot-loader.development.js:724)
        at Object.notify (Subscription.js:23)
        at Subscription.notifyNestedSubs (Subscription.js:60)
        at Connect.onStateChange (connectAdvanced.js:202)
        at Connect.onStateChange (react-hot-loader.development.js:724)
        at Object.notify (Subscription.js:23)
        at Subscription.notifyNestedSubs (Subscription.js:60)
        at Connect.onStateChange (connectAdvanced.js:202)
        at Connect.onStateChange (react-hot-loader.development.js:724)
        at Object.dispatch (redux.js:222)
        at e (<anonymous>:1:40553)
        at index.js:11
        at middleware.js:13
        at middleware.js:72
        at dispatch (redux.js:640)
        at index.js:196
```

Comment: Hi Kate... I'm getting the exact same issue. After a re-install it works and then later it stops working again... I don't have a soluton :( - it needs a fix!!

Comment: Hey Kate, I am updating my comment. Are you using maybe the plugin _lodash-webpack-plugin_ or something similar that alters the webpack.config.js config? It might happen that this can affect the lodash functions used

Comment: Hello Kiriakos, yes I use cra-rewire-lodash-plugin, you think  that it's can be a reason of such behavior? How do you think what plugin  I have to add in order to resolve this issue?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also same issue, I used lodash-webpack-plugin and it cause error. In lodash-wepback-plugin documentation written that flatten feature automatically removed and this cause error.
In webpack configuration file you can enable flatten feature:

```
new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin({
   'flattening': true,
});
```

It works for me

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's also work for me but at this case I don't see some  components from antd (((for example form items errors)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, ChartUtils.js at line 65 always returned the head of the data array as a string

```
_flatMap(data, function (entry) {
return getValueByDataKey(entry, key);
});
```

In my case I was using lodash-webpack-plugin, which mixed up lodash versions for different packages. If you step through lodash, you will see that:

```
function flatMap(collection, iteratee) {
return baseFlatten(map(collection, iteratee), 1);
}
```

will step into head, which always gets the first attribute of the array.

I stopped using lodash-webpack-plugin and LodashModuleReplacementPlugin, unfortunately i haven't found a way to exclude one npm package from the collection